# Icons and svg images display problem in ionic

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, ionic-framework

I'm developing an android app using ionic, I created a new app with side menu , when i run the app icons appear in the web browser and in simulator but don't appear in the my android device (oppo A5s cph1909 with color os5.2.1) i also tried with other mobiles like samsung and other oppo it works fine .i also tried before an svg image i got a bad structured image in the android device (oppo A5s).

Any idea?

[image]

[image]

Comment: debugg your device. open in chrome://inspect and send the results

Comment: i debugged my device with chrome://inspect    the result was , icons are displayed correctly on chrome debugger , and not displayed on device

Comment: when you debugg your device on chrome it wiill show exactly what has on your device. Its not possible that device show something and chrome something else.